# Prove that a Particular Set Is an Interval

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Suppose that $I$ is an interval in $\mathbb R$, and $f:  I \rightarrow \mathbb R$ is continuous on I.  My text (Stoll, Introduction to Real Analysis, 2nd Ed) proved that $f(I)$ is an interval by applying the intermediate value theorem to every point in $f(I)$.  Now, it is asking us to prove the same statement by the definition of connected set and the properties of continuous functions.  Specifically, show that, if $I$ is a connected set of $\mathbb R$ and $f:  I \rightarrow \mathbb R$ is continuous on $I$, f(I) is connected.

Just in case ... a set $X$ is disconnected if there are disjoint open sets $A, B$ such that $A \cap X, B \cap X$ are nonempty and $X \subset A \cup B$.  For continuity, we use the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition.

With $f(I)$, I'm attempting to prove by contradiction.  Suppose that $A \cap f(I), B \cap f(I)$ are nonempty and $f(I) \subset A \cup B$.  Let $y_k = f(x_k) \in A$ be arbitrary.  Select $\delta_k$ such that $N(y_k, \delta_k) \cap B = \emptyset$.  Since $f$ is continuous, $f^{-1}(N(y_k, \delta_k))$ is open relative to $I$, so $f^{-1}(N(y_k, \delta_k)) = I \cap O_k$.  Let $O = \bigcup_k O_k$.  Because of how we selected each $\delta_k$, $f(I \cap O) \cap B = \emptyset$.  Repeat the same process for each $y_m = f(x_m) \in B$.  Let $f^{-1}(N(y_m, \delta_m)) = I \cap J_m$.  Let $J = \bigcup_m J_m$.  Similarly, $f(I \cap J) \cap A = \emptyset$.

$I = \big\{ \bigcup_k (I \cap O_k) \big\} \bigcup \big\{ \bigcup_m (I \cap J_m) \big\} = I \cap (O \cup J) $ if and only if $O \cap J \ne \emptyset$.  Since $I$ is connected, $O \cap J \ne \emptyset$.  Now, what is my contradiction?  Both look correct: 
1.  $x \in I \cap (O \cap J) \rightarrow \big\{ \space f(x) \in f(I \cap O)$ and $f(x) \in f(I \cap J) \big\} \rightarrow f(x) \in f(I) \cap (A \cup B)^c$. 
2.  $x \in I \cap (O \cap J) \rightarrow \big\{ \space f(x) \in f(I \cap O)$ and $f(x) \in f(I \cap J) \big\} \rightarrow f(x) \in f(I) \cap (A \cap B)$. 
But you certainly cannot have 1 and 2 together, right?

Answer (score 1):

You're making it a bit too complicated. Suppose that $f:I\to\Bbb R$ is continuous, and $I$ is connected, i.e. it is an interval. Then $fI$ is connected, that is, it is also an interval. Argue by contraposition: suppose $fI$ was disconnected, say by disjoint open sets $U,V$. I claim $I$ is disconnected by the open disjoint sets $f^{-1}V$ and $f^{-1}U$. Can you prove this?